# Safari: "Failed to load resource: cancelled" in console. What does this mean?

Tags: safari, webkit

I am getting this error in the safari developer console:

> Failed to load resource: cancelled

What does this mean? I don't see any errors on the page, so why am I getting this message? I have an iframe on the page that is hidden when it loads, but it loads fine when I display it so I don't know why I'm getting this message.

Comment: have the same issue - did u find a solution ?